# Facebook tab app refuse to display in a frame

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-iframe

I've made a little Christmas themed Facebook app which I want to add on a page as a tab but I am running into some issues which makes the app unusable.

The site URL is the following: https://mariusvaduva.com/bradbattle/

If I do the first login there I run into no issues but unfortunately when I test it directly on the Facebook Page Tab, as a new user, after the login I receive a blank page instead of the iframe and the following error:

```
Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

This is how I get the login URL:

```
session_start();
require_once 'php/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'XXXXXX',
    'app_secret' => 'XXXXXX',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8'
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://mariusvaduva.com/bradbattle/callback.php');
```

And this is how I display the link:

```
<div id="login_container">
    <?php echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '"><img id="login_btn" src="img/login.png"></a>'; ?>
</div>
```

I've tried few suggestions including adding an .htaccess file with `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.facebook.com/` but with no success.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way of handling this? I really wanted to have this ready by this weekend. Any help or guidance is more than welcomed.

P.S. This is my callback file in case it helps:

```
session_start();
require_once 'php/Facebook/autoload.php';
require_once 'php/classes/class.database.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXXX',
  'app_secret' => 'XXXXXX',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8'
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
if (!isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('1849207942031149');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();
if (!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }
  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}
$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string)$accessToken;
try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$user = $response->getGraphUser();
$db = new Database();
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = "%s" LIMIT 1';
$db->prepare($sql,array($user['id']));
$data = $db->execute();
if (empty($data)) {
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES ("%s","%s")';
  $db->prepare($sql,array($user['id'],$user['name']));
  $data = $db->execute();
}
$_SESSION['user_id'] = (string)$user['id'];
$_SESSION['user_name'] = (string)$user['name'];
header('Location: https://mariusvaduva.com/bradbattle/bradbattle.php');
exit;
```

Comment: Browser support for ALLOW-FROM is still lacking. Your best bet is to remove the header altogether. If you did not actively set it anywhere yourself, then it is probably enabled in the general server configuration; when in doubt, ask your hoster/server admin.